# Ionic app data from html to php server

Tags: ionic-framework, http-post

I'm new to Ionic framework and am struggling to post data from HTML to PHP.

1.index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->


    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>


    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">HTML</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>

      <ion-view title="Signup">
     <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
      <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

    <ion-content class="has-header">
      <div class="list list-inset">

       <label class="item item-input">
         <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="userdata.username" placeholder="Enter Username">
       </label>

       <label class="item item-input">
         <input type="text" ng-model="userdata.email" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
       </label>

       <label class="item item-input">
         <input class="form-control" type="password" ng-model="userdata.password" placeholder="Enter Your Password">
       </label>

       <button class="button button-block button-positive button-dark" ng-click="signUp(userdata)">SignUp</button><br>
       <span>{{responseMessage}}</span>
     </div>
    </ion-content>

  </ion-view>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

2. app.js:

   ```
   .controller('SignupCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   $scope.signup = function () {
           var request = $http({
               method: "post",
               url: "http://myurl.com/signup.php",
               crossDomain : true,
               data: {
                   email: $scope.email,
                   password: $scope.password,
                   username: $scope.username
               },
               headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
           });
           /* Successful HTTP post request or not */
           request.success(function(data) {
               if(data == "1"){
                $scope.responseMessage = "Successfully Created Account";
               }
               if(data == "2"){
                $scope.responseMessage = "Create Account failed";
               }
               else if(data == "0") {
                $scope.responseMessage = "Email Already Exist"
               }  
           });
   }
   })
   ```

3.PHP file:

```
<?php
        header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

        $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $request = json_decode($postdata);
        $email = $postdata->email;
        $password = $postdata->password;
        $username = $postdata->username;

        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username",'password') or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());;
        mysql_select_db('dbname', $con);

        $qry_em = 'select count(*) as cnt from users where email ="' . $email . '"';
        $qry_res = mysql_query($qry_em);
        $res = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_res);

        if($res['cnt']==0){
        $qry = 'INSERT INTO users (name,pass,email) values ("' . $username . '","' . $password . '","' . $email . '")';
        $qry_res = mysql_query($qry);
            if ($qry_res) {
                echo "1";
            } else {
                echo "2";;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "0";
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit:** I wrote a detailed post on how to post data from Ionic to PHP and you can view it [here](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ionic/posting-data-from-ionic-app-to-php-server/).

In the `index.html` file you have:

```
ng-click="signUp(userdata)
```

but then in the `app.js` file you have this:

```
$scope.signup = function () {
```

instead of something like:

```
$scope.signup = function (userdata) {
```

If you would go this route then your data should look like this:

```
data: {
        email: userdata.email,
        password: userdata.password,
        username: userdata.username
}
```

**However**, you don't have to do it like this! You can do it like so that you remove the `userdata` from `ng-click="signUp(userdata)` and then in the app.js file in the data part you do it like this:

```
data: {
        email: $scope.userdata.email,
        password: $scope.userdata.password,
        username: $scope.userdata.username
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nikola. I changes the data, but still the data is not inserted into database. Please help me out.

Comment: On the client side (in your browser) check what headers are being sent when you click the save button. Then, on the server (php script) echo out the contents of the $request variable and see what that gives you. However, I'm wondering, why are you using `$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");` instead of for example `$_POST`?

Comment: we are using angular js, so we need json to be decoded before accessing the data and thats why we are using this method. this code works when the both html and php file is in same server. but in ionic , since it is in local, we are facing problems. thanks

Comment: @sansanthosh: I edited my answer with a link to my blog post which explains this step by step.

Comment: Either change `signUp` to `signup` or vice versa to avoid problems arising out of case-sensitivity in JavaScript.