# Ionic authentication REST web service using slim framework

Tags: frameworks, ionic-framework

I'm a beginner on the use of the Ionic framework, I'm trying to connect my application with server to get datas, so that I'm using a RESTfull web service developed on the Slim framework(response of request with JSON). The web service is already done, my problem now I don't know how to implement it in my application.

Comment: did you find my answer useful in the end?

Comment: not yet i'm  still looking

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a step by step tutorial just for this use case. You can view it here: http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ionic/posting-data-from-ionic-app-to-php-server/.

Btw, a similar question has also already been asked here: [Ionic app data from html to php server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752289/ionic-app-data-from-html-to-php-server/30753012#30753012).

Comment: Thanks Nikola, I appriciate your help but as i have described previously i used Slim framework as a REST  fresh frame.Please i need heip concernning this last .Thank you in advance for understanding and for listening keenly hoping for a response from you.

Comment: Well, tbh, this is not what your question suggests - you said you have a done api in slim framework and that you don't know how to connect to it from Ionic, and I provided you with that answer. Now, for help on Slim, I can't help because I never had dealt with it. Anyways, I see you're new here so I would kindly like to suggest that you read through the FAQ, cause this question may be closed because the question itself is not too clear on what you're asking and what **specific** problem you're having.

Comment: Thanks Nikola .I appriciate your help