# Implementation of REST web service using Slim framework on an ionic application to signin

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, slim

I'm a beginner in the use of the ionic framework , and I'm trying to implement a login and user authentication system using a RESTful web service developed on the Slim framework.  In fact, my client side is almost ready and my REST web service using the Slim framework also is ready and I tested that it works.

What I need to know is how to implement this last part with my application (client side).  I will need the http service of AngularJS but i don't understand how to do it.

Please, can you help me with examples or links?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ionic authentication REST web service using slim framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984481/ionic-authentication-rest-web-service-using-slim-framework)

Answer (score 1):

```
(function(){

angular.module('app')

.controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

  $scope.data = "";

  $scope.getData = function(){

    $http.get('urlToYourMethod')
    .success(function(data){
      $scope.data = data;
    })
    .error(function(er){

    });
  };

  $scope.getData();

}]);

})();
```

**Edit**

if you want to pass header parameters, the easiest way to do this is as follow:

```
var req = 
{
method : 'POST',
url : 'your url',
headers: {
  'Accept' : 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
},
data : output
};
```

Note :
-- headers depends on what you are sending and receiving.... There are info on headers here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

-- dataParameter needs to be `"data" : "test"` (not "myData" : "test")

-- If **GET** request, delete data parameter

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion.can you please tell me where can i add the autorization needed it in the header if i use  the $http.get() method, also when i use this last i have a JASON response i don't know how to get it  .Also if i will use   $http.post() how can i add the inputs prams.Thank you in advance for understanding and for listening keenly hoping for a response from you.

Comment: Should be good. Be aware: if making your REST API in other languages than Java, you might need to call your methods getMyinfo and call from angular $http.get('Myinfo')

Comment: Thanks gr3g, May i show  you how i did it my REST API using the slim framework concerning the authentication case , may be you can help me how can i shoud do it , please